# Sharing web content on Facebook and Twitter not working - WebKit iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit, sharing

I have a problem with sharing web content to facebook and twitter from my app which based on loading webpages into WebKit. In the webpage, I have 5 buttons: Facebook, Twitter, WhatsApp, Viber and SMS. All buttons except Facebook and Twitter works well. When the user clicks on WhatsApp, Viber and SMS, method "decidePolicyFor" is calling and I can to decide what will happen. Clicks on the Facebook and Twitter buttons runs nothing. There is no results and no errors.

I have also tried with implementing new QueriesSchemes into info.plist file but no results.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>sms</string>
    <string>viber</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>



func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
        print("user click")
        if let newURL = navigationAction.request.url,
            let host = newURL.host , !host.hasPrefix("-mywebsite-") && UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(newURL) && UIApplication.shared.openURL(newURL) {
            print(newURL)
            print("Redirected to browser. No need to open it locally")
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            print("Open it locally")
            let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString
            let url_elements = url!.components(separatedBy: ":")

            if url_elements[0] == "sms" {
                print("sms")
                openCustomApp(urlScheme: "sms://", additional_info: url_elements[1])
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else if url_elements[0] == "whatsapp"{
                print("whatsapp")
                openCustomApp(urlScheme: "whatsapp://", additional_info: url_elements[1])
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else if url_elements[0] == "viber"{
                print("viber")
                openCustomApp(urlScheme: "viber://", additional_info: url_elements[1])
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                print("unknown")
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("not a user click")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: After deep research, I've finally found a solution for my problem. Plugin which client using on the website by default is trying to open a new web window (in a web browser). In this case, I have to use a method:---> 


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {...} for handling. I hope this answer will be useful for someone.

Comment: I am successful to login with facebook in my website. But after login , i have some share content button with facebook. In that case , how to open the share window ? could you please help me ? I am getting the share and content url in decidePolicyFor navigationAction. But in createWebViewWith method , i find https://m.facebook.com/home.php. How to open the share window after login ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working fine..

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration:
 WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
 windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        NSLog("Test method call from another class", "")
         if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
             if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                 UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: [:],
 completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                 UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
             }
             return nil
         }
         return nil;

     }
```